# Is there any way to set different commands in a loop for the same right click menu?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to have a right click menu that gives me an option to delete whichever buttons I click
I have already done this in another function for i buttons in a list with the `command=lambda smth=i: func(smth)`
Is there any way to do this with a right click menu?

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
L = Label(root, text="Right-click to display menu",
          width=40, height=20)
L.pack()
smth = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
def func(smth):
    print(smth)
m = Menu(root, tearoff=0)
m.add_command(label="Delete")
for i in smth:
    m.config(command=lambda x: func(smth=i))
def do_popup(event):
    try:
        m.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    finally:
        m.grab_release()
L.bind("<Button-3>", do_popup)
mainloop()
```

If i put the `m.add_command(label='Delete')`
inside the for loop it will create multiple instances inside the right click menu, something which I dont desire

Any Ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am unsure what you are asking. When I run your code (after changing `m.config` to `m.add_command`) I get a menu with a single delete button as required.

Comment: @Henry Say for example I have multiple buttons. I want all of them to have the same label in the right click menu but each one to have a different command. For example if I have a loop that creates buttons ```for i in range(10):``` I can configure which command each one will have by simply saying ```tk.Button( [...], command=lambda number=i: myfunction(number))``` . How can I do that for a right click menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this using a global variable which holds a parameter related to the button right clicked (in this case the number). Then this is accessed in the `delete` function. I didn't find a built in way to do this.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
buttonRightClicked = None
def delete():
    global buttonRightClicked
    print(buttonRightClicked)

menu = tk.Menu(root, tearoff = 0)
menu.add_command(label = "Delete", command = delete)


def do_popup(event, x):
    global buttonRightClicked
    buttonRightClicked = x
    try:
        menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    finally:
        menu.grab_release()

for x in range(6):
    b = tk.Button(root, text = f"Button number {x}")
    b.grid(row = 0, column = x)
    b.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event, i = x: do_popup(event, i))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: YES YES YES! Not sure if its the right or wrong way because I'm not really experienced but thank you I was stuck in this for about 5 hours!

Comment: @Thalis ~ Consider marking this as the correct answer if this answered your question correctly. Click [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/775796) to learn how :D

Comment: Glad I could help. As @Cool Cloud said, please accept this answer if it was useful.

Comment: Yes, I did that! Have a nice day!